# Interact with a form using handle C#

Tags: c#, automation, pinvoke

I am trying to automate a dynamically appearing dialogue box.
I need to pass text to it,s text field and then press a button over this.
What I have tried so far.

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

IntPtr handle= FindWindowByCaption(System.IntPtr.Zero, "Caption Of File");
```

I am getting the handle of dialogue box correctly.

```
List<IntPtr> childWindows=  GetChildWindows(handle);//To get the child controls in this dialogue box
```

[Source](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows)

But when I try to cast it to control I get null.

```
foreach (IntPtr i in childWindows) 
{
    Control c = Control.FromHandle(i);
}
```

**So can any body tell what is wrong.I am supposing that I shall cast handle to control and then interact with control properties(e.g: text).**

Comment: Have you considered using an UI automation framework such as White to hide the complexity of dealing with Windows message? (http://code.google.com/p/white-project/) You can find an example here: http://scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET19&Lang=NL

Comment: I tried.I get exception.Unable to cast from Castle.Proxies.Win32ComboBoxProxy when try to cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I've been using code like this sucessfully for years to perform single sign on to an application that prompts the user for their username/pwd/domain.  The only caution is you need to know the control structure of the dialog you're targeting, but this is easily accomplished with Spy++ and rarely changes.  Of course you will need to modify this code for the control structure of your window.

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter,
            string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, string lParam);

        [DllImport("User32.Dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        private const uint WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
        private const uint WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;
        private const uint WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
        private const uint BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;
        private const uint WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;

        enum GetWindow_Cmd : uint
        {
            GW_HWNDFIRST = 0,
            GW_HWNDLAST = 1,
            GW_HWNDNEXT = 2,
            GW_HWNDPREV = 3,
            GW_OWNER = 4,
            GW_CHILD = 5,
            GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
        }

var dialog FindWindow("optionalClassNameHere", "Log On"); //Get the handle of the window
 var w3 = GetWindow(dialog , (uint)GetWindow_Cmd.GW_CHILD);  //I use GetWindow to walk the window controls
 var wUid = FindWindowEx(w3, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", "");
 var w4 = GetWindow(wUid, (uint)GetWindow_Cmd.GW_HWNDNEXT);
 var wPwd = FindWindowEx(w4 , IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", "");
 var wOK = FindWindowEx(w3, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK");
 SendMessage(wUid, WM_SETTEXT, 0, _WinDomain + "\\" + Username); //Send username to username edit control
 SendMessage(wPwd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, Password); //Send password to password edit control
 PostMessage(wOK, BM_CLICK, 0, 0); //Send left click(0x00f5) to OK button
```

Comment: Thanks JimStat.I am trying to select a combo box value.So instead of selecting combo box value.I am trying to set the  text of combo box(My file path).
I am trying following code.
SendMessage(ws3, 0x000C, 0, "My file path");//ws3 is handle of combo box.
Can you figure out what i am missing.

Comment: Khan - I believe you need to WM_SETTEXT to the "Edit" control that is a child of the ComboBox control.  See the screen shot I've added to the answer.

Comment: So in the screen shot I added to the answer you would want to get the handle of the first "Edit" control (000511CA) using the ComboBox handle (001B1174) as a starting point.  You could accomplish that using FindWindowEx or GetWindow and the GW_CHILD param.  Finally you would set the text with something like "SendMessage(hEditControl,WM_SETTEXT,"My file path").  Fyi - WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C

Answer (score 0):

Control.FromHandle can only work for controls in your process that are implemented by Control descendents. I'd guess this window is outside your process.

You need to use Win32 API methods to modify it.